# R How to set a data frame for a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying my hand at writing a package for R, I was going to do this in excel but I figured learning how to make a basic package would be interesting, and good knowledge to have.

I've gotten the function working, however each variable has to be referenced as a column form the data set individually eg. DATA$D1 etc. I would like to know how to make it cleaner so the function has data has its own an argument, that way the name of the data set only needs to be given once. In the same way say the aov {stats} package works, where the columns are listed and the data frame is set.
AOV example (Val, Location are columns of data set starlings):

```
aov(Val~Location, data=starlings)
```

My Function:

```
#' Run PCQ Density Calculation
#' Take four distance measurements and specified area and estimate density.
#' @param A = Specified Area (i.e. 1m^2 or 1 hectare (10,000 m^2))
#' @param D1 = Quarter 1 Distance
#' @param D2 = Quarter 2 Distance
#' @param D3 = Quarter 3 Distance
#' @param D4 = Quarter 4 Distance
#' @return The density esitmation 
#' @export
PCQ <- function(A,D1,D2,D3,D4){
  return(A^2/((D1+D2+D3+D4)/4)^2)
}
```

My Function in use (D1,D2,D3,D4 are columns of the data set dat):

```
PCQ(1,dat$D1,dat$D2,dat$D3,dat$D4)
```

I've tried having the function have a variable "D" what would hold the data sets name, then have the $D1 etc. in the function but that didn't work.

```
PCQ <- function(D,A,D1,D2,D3,D4){
      return(A^2/((D$D1+D$D2+D$D3+D$D4)/4)^2)
    }
```

Sorry for the lack of clarity on the first edit.

Answer (score 1):

Or try this

```
dat <- data.frame(P.1st = 1:10)
PCQ <- function(df, var1) {
  col <- deparse(substitute(var1))    
  return(cumsum(df[, col]))
}
PCQ(dat, P.1st)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

Comment: I've edited my question because I didn't explain it so well the first time.

Comment: You should be able to adapt your code using the simplified example. There may also be numerous alternatives. You could e.g. use to dots `PCQ <- function(df, ...) { cols <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse) }` and reference the first argument within the function using `df[, cols[1]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PCQ <- function(data,A,D1,D2,D3,D4){
  return(A^2/((data[,D1] + data[,D2] + data[,D3] + data[,D4])/4)^2)
  }
```

This function can be used as

```
PCQ(data = dat,1,"P.1st","P.2nd","P.3rd","P.4th")
```

Comment: Yes this works thank you!
Though it would be nice if it were possible to not have to used " " for each column
Is there a list of these operators? and how they can be used in this way, I've had trouble finding one

Comment: What do you mean by is there a list of these operators? i cant understand

Comment: I've been using R for basic statistics at university but they haven't really taught much on what things mean, other than giving code to run and being able to work it out from there.

What is $ [] , and . mean in R where can I find a guide on these things as I have no idea what they are called, hence why I called them operators.

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple column names to the function without quoting them we can use advantages of package `lazyeval`

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:50, ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("C", 1:10))))
#   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
# 1  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41  46
# 2  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42  47
# 3  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43  48
# 4  4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44  49
# 5  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45  50
PCQ <- function(D, A, ...)
{
  require("lazyeval")
  cols <- lazy_dots(...)
  cols_names <- unlist(lapply(cols, function(x) as.character(x$expr)))

  return( A^2 / (rowSums(D[,cols_names])/4)^2 )
} 

PCQ(dat, 100, C1, C5, C7, C10)
# [1] 16.32486 15.08153 13.97502 12.98596 12.09830
```

But more beautiful solution may be created with function `select` from `dplyr` package.

```
PCQ2 <- function(D, A, ...)
{
  require("dplyr")

  return( A^2 / (rowSums(select(D, ...))/4)^2 )
}

PCQ2(dat, 100, C1, C5, C7, C10)
# [1] 16.32486 15.08153 13.97502 12.98596 12.09830
```